# Can I map the TIMESTAMP corresponding to an HBase column value to a VIEW created in Apache Phoenix?

Tags: apache-phoenix

In the Apache Phoenix [FAQ](https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html#How_I_map_Phoenix_table_to_an_existing_HBase_table), we learn how to map an existing HBase table to a Phoenix view.

Seperately, the Phoenix [documentation](https://phoenix.apache.org/rowtimestamp.html) describes how to create a Phoenix table with a ROW_TIMESTAMP comprising part of the primary key.

I have an HBase table that maps relationships between users on an app.  The CREATE VIEW syntax is:

```
CREATE VIEW RELATIONSHIPS (RELATIONSHIP_ID varchar primary key, F.FOLLOWING_ID varchar, F.FOLLOWER_ID varchar);
```

My question is: how could I amend this syntax if I wanted to include the TIMESTAMP from one of those columns in my Phoenix view?  I cannot get any variant of the code from the documentation to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to create a VIEW that contains information of timestamp of each record in HBase. According to the [doc](https://phoenix.apache.org/rowtimestamp.html):

> The value of the column cannot be null (since it is directly mapped to HBase row timestamp). This also means a column can be declared as ROW_TIMESTAMP **only when creating the table**.